# Firebase integration leads to "Firebase is not defined" error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to use Firebase as my back-end but so far I have failed to get the correct integration  from the grunt terminal I get this error:

> Firebase is not defined, 
>   username is defined but never used and
>   password is defined but never used.

despite creating the account in firebase

I don't want to store my authentication inside the controller

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name mealsApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the mealsApp
 */
angular.module('mealsApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

    // var Firebase = require("firebase");

    var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://orderapp-d2948.firebaseio.com/");

    $scope.SignIn = function($scope) {
        var username = $scope.user.email;
        var password = $scope.user.password;

     myFirebaseRef.createUser({
      email    : "atinababy24@gmail.com",
      password : "Dreamteam@14"
    }, function(error, userData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
      }
    });

    }; 

});
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I am having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Nope. it didn't work.

Comment: I managed to make it work. if you are using console (new firebase) you need to add the script that you'll get in settings. let me know if you need help with that.